# Can't fetch NetworkImage for Flutter from Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: flutter, ssl, networking, google-cloud-storage

I want to load a `NetworkImage` in Flutter but can't get it to work because of a:

```
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

Does *not* work (Image from Google Cloud Storage + Cloud CDN)

```dart
NetworkImage("https://cdn.vaandra.com/items/f69f662f-41ff-4bb1-bd50-75a70b7ca6a5/439806b1-cacc-4d58-85a5-601bcb825fe3-p-500")
```

However this does work (test image from the webz)

```dart
NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9")
```

This is the full error message:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following HandshakeException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:99:46)
#1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:142:25)
#2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:911:54)
#3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1040:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://cdn.vaandra.com/items/f69f662f-41ff-4bb1-bd50-75a70b7ca6a5/439806b1-cacc-4d58-85a5-601bcb825fe3-p-500", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://cdn.vaandra.com/items/f69f662f-41ff-4bb1-bd50-75a70b7ca6a5/439806b1-cacc-4d58-85a5-601bcb825fe3-p-500", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Although the error claims that this is a certificate problem I can't understand how it does work with that public image that also comes through `https`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that extends the http override

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}
```

And use it in the main function

```
void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it did work! However it seems a bit like a workaround. Isn't there an idiomatic way?

Comment: This is the only workaround i found that is easy to implement